# progressive string mixed with int generation

Tags: php, mysql

I'm encountering a problem with the generation of a number which increases everytime an operation is called.

When the value arrive to 10, i can't print 11 and so on...

```
    $this->sql = "SELECT codice FROM accettazione ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

    if ($result = $this->hookUp->query($this->sql)) {

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($rw = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {

                (int)$codice = substr($rw['codice'], -1);

                if ($codice < 9) {
                    $rw['codice'] = date("Y") . ".0000";
                } else /*if ($codice == 9 || $codice < 99)*/ {
                    $rw['codice'] = date("Y") . ".000";
                }

                echo $rw['codice'] . ++$codice;
            }
        } else {
            echo date("Y") . ".00001";
        }

    } else if ($this->hookUp->query($this->sql) === false) {
        echo "fail";
    }
}
```

The goal is to print 00001 when the value is lower than 10, ++00010 when lower than 100, ++00100 when lower than 1000, and so on...

When the code is 00010, at 00011, the value goes back to 00001 (if ($result->num_rows > 0) isn't satisfied anymore).

In the mySQL table, $rw["codice"] is a VARCHAR.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want your values displayed with leading zeros.  That is:

```
     1  displayed as 00001
     9  displayed as 00009
    11  displayed as 00011
  1234  displayed as 01234
```

This is a requirement as old as the [IBM 029 keypunch machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keypunch#IBM_029_Card_Punch). (If I guess incorrectly, please edit your question.)

It's easy in php using [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

```
$string_codice = sprintf('%05d', $codice);
```

**EDIT**

I think you're doing this the hard way. It looks like you want a string that reads   `2015.00001` or `2015.09876` or suchlike.  But I'm not confident guessing your requirements from your code. For one thing, I don't know what the values in your `codice` column in your database table look like.

Maybe you could try something like this.

```
   /* assume the counter starts at zero */
   $codice = 0;
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        /* fetch the counter value from the table if nay. */
        while ($rw = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
            (int)$codice = $rw['codice'];  /* no substr */
        }
    }
    /* add one to the value and format it YYYY.000nn */
    $codice++;
    $stringval = date("Y") . "." . sprintf('%05d', $codice); 
    echo $stringval;
```

Comment: Yes, but even passing the $string_codice, the situation doesn't change. I mean, i don't have to use the if condition anymore, but, after having inserted the tenth value (00010), when I insert the eleventh, it shows me 00001 and not 00011. Can you explain me better how to use this on my function? Maybe is not the sprintf function, but something else.